# make space in a list with string

Tags: python, list

Hi is there any function that takes a list

`['-x','+2x','-3x']`

and makes a space after the operators like this

`['- x','+ 2x','- 3x']`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please make an attempt before asking.

Comment: There's most likely no such function - you'll have to write one yourself

Comment: Is the operator always present, always one character, and always the first character? If so this is trivial using basic string slicing.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = ['-x','+2x','-3x']
newString = [ n1.replace('-','- ').replace('+','+ ') for n1 in string ]
print(newString)
['- x', '+ 2x', '- 3x']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 1):

You could inert a space at the second position for each string in the list using a list comprehension:

```
terms = ['-x','+2x','-3x']
terms = [t[:1]+' '+t[1:] for t in terms]

['- x', '+ 2x', '- 3x']
```